# Watch a DOM property

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers, mutation

I'm trying to monitor the DOM element on a third-party website. The element is non-existent until a countdown timer reaches, then it is created.

I've had some success playing around with: document.getElementsByClassName('countdown ng-hide').length

when it changes from 0 to 1 I want to effect a function.

How would I do this? I've tried using a Mutation Observer but it won't let me observe a null node.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I've got so far.

```
var timesDone = 0; 
var songID = 0; 
function clickit(xsongID) { 
if(document.getElementsByClassName('lottery-countdown ng-hide').length == 1) { 

document.getElementsByClassName('media submission ng-scope')[xsongID].click(); songName = document.getElementsByClassName('media-title submission-name ng-binding')[xsongID].outerHTML; timesDone++; } 

} 
setInterval(clickit, 29900, songID);
```

Comment: You can pull the value of countdown on a `setInterval` timer and act when it reaches end. Or you can observe the parent of your node for addition of children

Comment: One question, how is it possible to monitor a dom node in 3rd party website via JavaScript???

Comment: JavaScript console in Chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this recently by setting up an Interval function like this :

```
var timesTest = 0;
var checkExists = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.yourClassElement').length) {
       // ok element found : do your stuff and clear the Interval...
       // stuff...
       clearInterval(checkExists);
       timesTest = 0;
     }
     timesTest++;
     // I won't let this run more than 5 seconds, so :
     if (timesTest*100 > 5000)
        clearInterval(checkExists);
}, 100);
```

Comment: I'm using an interval, it's great, but not perfect. If you want to change the properties of function, (say, the ID of the thing you want to change) you have to clear the interval and start a new one, as the interval function doesn't change.